# Does ball type affect the distance a captured Pokemon can be thrown?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Some types of Pokeballs have different throw ranges when catching Pokémon. Do the different Pokeball throw ranges apply to captured Pokémon? IE: Can a Pokémon caught in a Feather Ball be thrown further than a Pokémon caught in a Heavy Ball?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Wondercricket's video](https://twitter.com/i/status/1495529001598668803) demonstrates no range difference, and no difference in how fast the balls fly. However, the animations and sound effects are different, and the Gigaton Ball takes longer to leave the player's hand than the other balls tested.

We examine the animation in terms of 3 critical frames per throw. Frame A is the frame in the throw animation where the ball moves to the left of the character's head. This seems to be roughly the start of the throw animation. Frame B is the frame where the ball leaves the character's hand, and Frame C is the first frame where the purple glow of the Pokemon return animation is visible.

The video was downloaded with [this thing](https://twittervideodownloader.com/) that popped up when I googled "twitter video downloader", and examined in the Video Editor app that comes with Windows 10, in case that matters.

---

In Wondercricket's video, the Ultra Ball throw has Frame A at timestamp 1.00, Frame B at timestamp 1.06 (2 frames later), and Frame C at timestamp 2.36 (39 frames after Frame B).

The Gigaton Ball throw has Frame A at timestamp 4.60, Frame B at timestamp 4.76 (5 frames later), and Frame C at timestamp 6.10 (40 frames after Frame B).

The Jet Ball throw has Frame A at timestamp 7.76, Frame B at timestamp 7.83 (2 frames later), and Frame C at timestamp 9.16 (40 frames after Frame B).

From leaving the player's hand to hitting the ground, the timings are almost identical, with the variance explained by Wondercricket's slightly higher aim on the second and third throws. However, the Gigaton Ball was 3 frames slower to leave the player's hand.

Comment: Well I'll be darn. I could've sworn the speeds were difference; even Pinkerman made the same conclusion. Thanks for breaking it down though!

Comment: @Wondercricket I roughly tried to measure them with a stopwatch, starting when I pressed A and stopping when the ball hit the ground, and there were more or less 0.1-0.15s difference between Heavy and Fether ball. So all the difference is just in the time that the ball needs to leave the character's hand

Answer (score 9):

After doing some tests in the village with 3 pokemon caught in an Ultra Ball, Jet Ball, and Gigaton Ball, there was no difference in how far I could throw the Pokémon. I was able to throw all three pokeball types from the gate to roughly where the hair salon was located.

<strike>However,there was a *speed* difference when throwing the various pokeball</strike>. Here is a [video](https://twitter.com/i/status/1495529001598668803) I recorded showing the equal distance and speeds, which [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395784/124566) broke down more accurately

Comment: Your video actually shows the balls flying at the same speed. The Gigaton Ball takes a bit longer to leave the character's hand, but other than that, the perceived speed difference is mostly due to the animations looking faster or slower. I've posted an answer analyzing the video in terms of frame counts.

Answer (score 7):

I did some testing, and my opinion is **no**:  throw distances are the same.
From the same spot, aiming at the same item, and fully loaded throw, *Leaden ball* distance is exactly the same as *Wing ball*.
(I haven't unlocked Gigaton and Jet yet, but they shouldn't make any difference.)

However, the throw speed seems different. "Heavy" balls appears to be slower than "Feather" counterparts.

Comment: I also noticed the speed in throwing, and was going to post a video of it. Anywho, here’s a link to it: https://twitter.com/btwondercricket/status/1495529001598668803?s=21

Comment: @Wondercricket you should post your own answer, video proof deserves to be the accepted one :)

Comment: Since you post the answer first, feel free to just include it into your answer :)

Comment: @Wondercricket I posted first only because you were recording :) I don't want to take the credit